# How to input time series data in R?

Tags: r, time, arima

I'm rather new at R so I appreciate your help in advance.

I have an excel spreadsheet dataset including daily, closing prices for a financial asset ranging from Jan 3rd 2000 all the way to Mar 6th 2019. I am looking to use ARIMA models to forecast future prices for this asset but cannot input the data in R.

Simply put, I have an Excel file with 2 columns and 4736 rows as per below:

```
03/jan/00   1,8358
04/jan/00   1,8702
05/jan/00   1,8520
.
.
.
01/mar/19   3,7824
06/mar/19   3,8372
```

Right after reading the file using the command `read_excel(file.choose())` I've tried using ts commands to read the data as a time series. However considering data is only collected during market closing times on business days, this does not produce the desired results. Also tried researching and read about `xts` and `zoo`-type series but do not seem to be able to make these work. Please note that this data excludes weekends and holidays, which seems to be the root of the problem here.

```
my_data <- read_excel(file.choose())
series <- ts(my_data, start=c(2000,1,3), end=c(2019,3,6), frequency = 252)
```

By using ts considering an average 252 business days per year, my time series ends on a different date as it should.

What kind of steps should I consider in order to 1) read the data from the excel file and 2) read the imported data in R as a time series?

Also thought about, instead of using dates as the first column, use numbers from 1 through 4736 to eliminate this necessity but it seems the first column is required to have the YYYY-m-d format.

Thanks a ton

Comment: You probably need `my_data[,1] <- as.POSIXct(my_data[,1], format="%d/%b/%y")`, assuming your date really is your first column.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This seems to work better than ts, however it looks as though it reads the date as one of the variables. Does this mean everytime I work with the prices, I need to refer to the data as my_data[,2]?

Comment: No. Two things: (1) I used `[,1]` because I do not know your real column names. If the question were really reproducible, I'd be able to see real data including names and such. With frames, you can always refer to a column both numerically (`[,1]`) and by-name (`[["id"]]`, `[,"id"]`, and `$id`, albeit with different `list`/`vector` behavior). (2) The intent is to help your time-series efforts: typically, there needs to be actual **time**. What you were providing previous was **string**, since `"03/jan/00"` is vastly different from `as.POSIXct("03/jan/00",format="%d/%b/%y")`.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

1) `read_excel` should read it in as a `tibble`. In case dates are read as values use `janitor::excel_numeric_to_date` to convert to correct date

2) To format date use `lubridate`. In your case `dmy` function would be it.

3) then convert the `tibble` to `xts` using `tbl2xts`; vignette:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tbl2xts/vignettes/tbl2xts_vignette.html